# Constructive, inductive proofs

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I was trying to prove that a tree of order n always has n-1 edges. I came up with essentially the same proof as: [Soundness of a simple tree edge count proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981264/soundness-of-a-simple-tree-edge-count-proof-by-induction).

I was told my proof was incorrect for the same reason that the accepted answer in the linked question gave.

To be clear, my primary question is: **why is it valid to create a order n tree from an order n+1 tree, but not the other way around?** Any justification I can come up with seems to hold for both ways equally.

Here is a rough outline of my proof:

Base case: a (simple) graph with a single vertex can not have any edges.

For the inductive case, assume T is a tree of order n with n-1 edges. Now create some graph T1 by adding a vertex v to T. Now the question is: what edges can be added in order for T1 to be a tree?

In order for T1 to be a tree, only a single edge can be added. If no edges are added, then T1 is not connected. If 2 or more edges are added, then T1 will contain a cycle.

**EDIT**

I am specifically looking for a difference. Why is one approach valid while the other is not?

Comment: Just a bit of general advice: It's almost always better to go "backward" with an induction proof. You hand me *any* object of size $n+1$, I break it into an object of size $n$ plus some leftover piece, then I draw some conclusion about the two pieces together.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2237668/what-are-families-of-graphs-called-which-we-can-grow-by-induction) for an example where the $n$ to $n+1$ induction step is not valid.

Comment: @AustinMohr. Thanks for the tip. In this example: going from n to n+1 yields only an existence proof that _some_ order n tree has n-1 edges; going from n+1 to n will yield a universal proof that _all_ order n tress have n-1 edges. In essence, when going from n+1 to n, you avoid having to prove some "Tree Growing Algorithm". I suspect this is roughly why your advice holds in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof doesn't show the fact that **each** tree on $n + 1$ vertices can be constructed in this way. Therefore you can't state that each tree on $n + 1$ vertices has $n$ edges. You show only that there are some trees (at least $1$) on $n + 1$ vertices with $n$ edges.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My question is still the same. I understand this is the problem in going from n to n+1 vertices (sorry if that was not clear). But why is this not an issue going the other way: from n+1 vertices to n vertices?

Comment: Because when going from $n+1$ to $n$, you are free to remove *any* vertex from the tree in any way that results in another tree. In particular, you can remove a  leaf vertex. Then you must only show that any $n+1$ vertex tree has such a leaf vertex, and that removing it results in another tree. This reduces the problem to one already assumed solved (via the inductive hypothesis). In somewhat loose terms-you pick leaves until you reach the root.

Comment: You can say something like "Let us be given *any* tree on $n+1$ vertices" at the start of your induction, so there's no chance of missing a tree of that order. When you remove a leaf, you are guaranteed to get *some* tree on $n$ vertices. Since the induction hypothesis holds for all trees of that order, it does not matter which tree arises after deleting the vertex.

Comment: @DavidWheeler. Aha! In sum: Start with an arbitrary tree and "pick leaves until you reach the root." This is fully general because you started with an arbitrary tree. The other way around is not fully general because it is not obvious you can reach all trees by following the procedure in my original (invalid) argument. I appreciate the insight.